# Check if user is logged in and make page unreachable

Tags: php

What is the best way to check if a user is logged in and if its not make the page unreachable for him?

What does this code need to make it complete and safe:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['USER_ID']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Kill the script

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['USER_ID']))
  die();
```

Or print a friendly message, redirect to login page, or whatever you think is an appropriate response. Just kill the page before showing your premium content.

Answer (score 0):

In Login page Add

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['id'];
```

In page which you want to make unreachable if not loggedin, Add at top

```
include ("auth.php");
```

***auth.php***

```
 <?php
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['user_id']){
    header("location:index.php");   //page you want to redirect
}
?>
```

Now you can add auth.php in any page which you want to make unreachable if not logged in...

Comment: This code is redirecting when the user is logged in. But it must redirect when it is not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need -before any page output (even warnings and errors):

```
session_start();
```

So your code would be complete as follow:

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['USER_ID'])) {
   header ("Location: login.php");
   die;
}
```

Comment: This code is redirecting when the user is logged in. But it must redirect when it is not logged in.

Comment: You are mistaken @John , it does exactly the opposite you said: `!isset($_SESSION['USER_ID'])` means: _NOT EXIST (OR DEFINED) THE USER_ID SESSION_

Answer (score 0):

if USER_ID could not be blank it is better to check this too:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['USER_ID'] && $_SESSION['USER_ID'] != ''))
```

As a personal method for more complex login check: generate a random token when user did login and store it in database and put in an extra session. Then check if user_id session name and random session match together by a database check. This will prevent attacks by any type of fraud in session and cookies name.

Comment: Even better: `if (!empty($_SESSION['USER_ID']))` don't you think? empty() doc: [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: Thank you. Yes. empty() do both of checks together.I emphasized not to forget the blank check.